# Создание представлений (view) SQL

Tags: sql, view

Как создать представление, с проверкой. И если представление есть, то его не добавлять?

`create view if not exists statistic as`   - это не работает
`create view or replace statistic as`  - это пересоздаёт представление, а мне пересоздавать его зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о MS SQL

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 1
    FROM sys.views
    WHERE Name = 'MyView'
)
BEGIN    
    EXEC('CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT 1 as [Value]');    
END
```

Comment: а почему через `exec` ?

Comment: @teran потому что по-другому `CREATE` в блоке `BEGIN... END` не выполнить.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ,  отметьте его как верный и проголосуйте за него.